# Как написать специализацию begin() для C-строки?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Хочу заставить работать цикл `for(auto c:s)` для обычной строки в духе C (0-завершенной). Работаю с Visual C++ 2015. Попытался специализировать шаблон `begin()`:

```
template<>
inline const char* begin(const char*& _Cont) noexcept
{
    return _Cont;
}
```

Увы, фокус не удался - ошибка C2912, *явная специализация (см. выше) не является специализацией функции-шаблона*. Соответственно, вопрос первый - почему?

Если просто написать перегрузку

```
inline const char* begin(const char*& Cont)
{
    return Cont;
}
```

ничуть не лучше - ошибка C3312, *не найдена вызываемая функция `begin` для типа `const char*`*. Замена в перегрузке `begin(const char*& Cont)` на `begin(const char* Cont)`, само собой, не спасает.

Вопрос второй - вроде, по всем канонам, при разрешении шаблонов и перегрузки должна быть выбрана перегрузка? Или здесь не просто вызов функции и это правило не работает?

Ну, и третий вопрос - это вообще можно, то, что я хочу, или нет? и если да - то как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Всё ведь совсем просто, не понимаю зачем Вы полезли в дебри шаблонов:</s>

```
#include <iostream>

const char* begin(const char* str) noexcept
{
    return str;
}

const char* end(const char* str) noexcept
{
    int count = strlen(str);
    return str + count;
}

int main()
{
    for(auto c : "Hello Moscow!")
        std::cout << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

---

На деле оказалось не так просто. Пример выше будет работать даже если убрать мою реализацию `begin/end`(т.е. она не используется). Видимо есть перегрузка для массивов в std для `begin/end`, а вот чтобы `for` заработал для `const char*` нужно написать следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std
{
    const char* begin(const char* str) noexcept
    {
        return str;
    }

    const char* end(const char* str) noexcept
    {
        int count = strlen(str);
        return str + count;
    }
}


int main()
{
    const char* str = "Hello Moscow!";
    for(auto c: str)
        std::cout << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Но с этим кодом есть проблема: стандарт явно запрещает засорять namespace std подобными реализациями. Поэтому, в силу чисто академического интереса можно и посмотреть на это, но вот использовать лучше не стоит(<s>хотя Вы вряд ли нарвётесь на неприятности</s>). По другому сделать не получится, <s>потому как `for` внутри себя, скорее всего, использует `std::begin`/`std::end`</s>

---

**Обновление 2:** всё вышесказанное относится лишь к студии. В других компиляторах это не работает, а это значит, что `std::begin/std::end` могут быть вызваны в студии, но для этого кода они не будут вызваны ни в clang ни в gcc. Что это всё значит? Это значит, что `for` для `const char*` работать не будет.

---

**Обновление 3:** Почему не работает попытка специализации шаблона(как в вопросе) внутри `namespace std`?(из комментариев). Дело в том, что в заголовках студии есть следующие перегруженные функции для std::begin:
Раз

```
template<class _Container>
auto inline begin(_Container& _Cont) -> decltype(_Cont.begin())
```

Два

```
template<class _Container>
auto inline begin(const _Container& _Cont) -> decltype(_Cont.begin())
```

И три

```
template<class _Ty, size_t _Size> 
inline_CONST_FUN _Ty *begin(_Ty (&_Array)[_Size]) _NOEXCEPT
```

Так вот, написав:

```
template<>
inline const char* begin(const char*& _Cont) noexcept
```

Мы начинаем проверять, какой шаблон мы специализируем. Начнём с первого — проверка не проходит, почему? Потому что `decltype(_Cont.begin())` не скомпилируется, т.к. у `const char*` нет метода `begin()`, поэтому срабатывает SFINAE и вариант отбраковывается. То же происходит и со вторым вариантом. Остается третий вариант, который принимает массив и из него извлекат 2 необходимых параметра шаблона, но у нас ведь указатель, поэтому этот вариант тоже отбраковывается. И у нас остается ... ничего! Вот и ошибка компилятора, что специализация не имеет общего случая, который специализировать.

Приведу пример, как можно сделать специализацию для первого и третьего случая:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace std
{
    template<>
    int *begin(int(&_Array)[50]) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Yeah!\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<>
    auto inline begin(const std::vector<int>& _Cont) -> decltype(_Cont.begin())
    {
        std::cout << "Beah!\n";
        return _Cont.begin();
    }
}


int main()
{
    int a[50];
    std::begin(a);
    std::begin(std::vector<int>{});
}
```

Но этот код не компилируется 2015 студией. Причина мне не ясна(ей не нравится специализация для контейнера), видимо баг в студии(создал [bug-report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2340007)), т.к. другие компиляторы такой код компилируют на ура(для clang надо будет поправить `noexcept`).

Comment: Почему тогда у меня это не сработало - я же делал просто перегрузку `begin(const char* Cont)` ?

Ага, я тут посмотрел... У меня не так вызов идет (простите, в комментарии не пойму как код отформатировать...) -


    const char * s ="Hello";
    for(auto c: s)
    {
        cout << c;
    }

В чем тут *принципиальная* разница?..

Comment: @Harry, обновил ответ

Comment: Тогда куда понятнее :)
Сейчас еще для полной очистки все же попробую специализировать шаблон в пространстве имен std, и тогда вопрос можно считать исчерпанным...
Спасибо!

Comment: что-то не хватает IQ добиться того же с помощью специализации шаблонов... Не распространится ваша любезность и на этот случай? :)

Comment: @Harry, специализировать можно ранее объявленный общий шаблон. Что вы пытаетесь специализировать, когда общего случая у Вас нет?

Comment: У VC++ есть общий шаблон - 

`template<class _Container>
 auto inline begin(_Container& _Cont) -> decltype(_Cont.begin())
 { 
 return (_Cont.begin());
 }

template<class _Container>
 auto inline begin(const _Container& _Cont) -> decltype(_Cont.begin())
 { 
 return (_Cont.begin());
        }`

который я и пытаюсь специализировать. Опять извините за неформатированность...

Comment: Вроде бы специализация шаблонов из `std::` юзеровским кодом не запрещена?

Comment: @ixSci Шаблон я нашел, не совсем к делу относящийся, извините, вошел в заблуждение сам и туда же потянул вас :)

Comment: @VladD, только если эта специализация зависит от пользовательского типа, чем `const char*`, само собой, не является.

Comment: @Harry, Вы нашли относящийся к делу шаблон, но мне сложно сходу сказать в чём проблема, попробую завтра посмотреть и отпишу здесь если что.

Comment: `for(auto c : "Hello Moscow!")` тут строка имеет тип `T[N]`, для таких случает `begin`/`end` действительно определён. Во втором случае - `T*` для них не существует общего случае обнаружения границы, поэтому опасно, поэтому не определено.

Comment: @ixSci Ну как, вам удалось понять, в чем у меня проблемы? :)

Comment: @Harry, обновил ответ.